# Почему родитель формы равен Null?

Tags: c#, winforms, null

Выдержка кода из главной формы:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public NetComm.Host server;
    public NetComm.Client client;
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ToolStripMIConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientPref formConnect = new ClientPref();
        formConnect.Owner = this;
        formConnect.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Выдержка кода из создаваемой формы:

```
public partial class ClientPref : Form
{
    Main formMain;
    public ClientPref()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        formMain = this.Owner as Main;
    }
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (formMain != null) //следующий бок не выполняется т.к. formMain равен null
        {
            if (IsAddressValid(this.txtBoxIP.Text))
            {
            formMain.ClientStart(Convert.ToInt32(this.txtBoxPort.Text), this.txtBoxIP.Text, "Соперник");
            }
            else toolTipClient.Show("Введен некорректный IP-адрес.", this.txtBoxIP);
        }

    }
```

Почему formMain равен null или как в итоге обратиться к методу ClientStart формы Main?

Comment: потому что когда выполняется код `formMain = this.Owner as Main;` owner еще не установлен, поэтому `formMain` всегда _null_

Comment: Или уносите Owner в конструктор формы, или читайте его на Loaded событии.

Comment: На будущее - лучше не писать код в формах. Всмысле, код запуска клиента - не код формы, зависеть от конкретного экземпляра - не должен. Но что почитать на эту тему - даже не могу подсказать к сожалению.

Comment: когда вы вызываете formMain.ClientStart из ClientPref, то тем самым нарушаете один из основных принципов ООП. и увеличиваете связанность кода. почитайте мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой вариант - переписать вот так, сделать поле вычислимым свойством:

```
Main FormMain { get { return this.Owner as Main } };
```

Тогда в `btnConnect_Click` всё должно работать.

Comment: После вашего ответа понял, что можно было даже без объявления `formMain` в `btnConnect_Click` написать просто `(this.Owner as Main).ClientStart(Convert.ToInt32(this.txtBoxPort.Text), this.txtBoxIP.Text, "Соперник");`

Answer (score 1):

Когда выполняется код

```
formMain = this.Owner as Main;
```

owner еще не установлен, так как он устанавливается после выполнения конструктора, поэтому formMain всегда null

Решить можно передавая параметр в конструктор, для этого надо добавить конструктор с параметром

```
public ClientPref(Main owner):this()
{
    formMain = this.Owner as Main;
}
```

и вызывать уже его

```
private void ToolStripMIConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientPref formConnect = new ClientPref(this);
    formConnect.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Если ClientPref - это диалог, то его надо сделать независимым и он не должен управлять формой, т.е. в диалоге не должно быть вызова `formMain.ClientStart(...)`, т.к. это нарушает один из основных принципов дизайна в ООП - [принцип единственной обязанности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) (англ. **Single responsibility principle - SRP**).

Диалог должен получить данные от пользователя, проверить их и предоставить доступ к этим данных. Больше никакой обязанности у диалога быть не должно.     Посмотрите, например, на OpenFileDialog, в нем нет ссылки на главную форму.

Чтобы диалог ClientPref сделать независимым, надо значения, выбранные пользователем, сохранять в свойствах диалога.

```
public partial class ClientPref : Form {

  public int Port { get; private set; }
  public string IP { get; private set; }

  void Validate() {
    if (IsAddressValid(this.txtBoxIP.Text)) {
      this.Post = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtBoxPort.Text);
      this.IP = this.txtBoxIP.Text;
    }   
  }
}
```

В диалоге надо перехватывать нажатие <kbd>Esc</kbd> -- работающий **пример диалога [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480925/196972)**.

Для вызова диалога и получения данных из него, в главной форме пишем:

```
var fc = new ClientPref();
if(fc.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   ClientStart(fc.Port, fc.IP);
```

т.е. форма решает когда вызвать диалог и что делать с данными введенными пользователем.

---

Если по какой-то причине надо получить ссылки на все открытые формы, то это можно сделать так:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

var forms = Application.OpenForms;
```

Открытую форму определенного типа можно получить так

```
using System.Linq;

var main = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Main>().First();
```

Если есть несколько форм одинакового типа, то их можно отпичать по значению свойства Name, но таких ситуаций лучше избегать.

---

Почему нежелательно передавать ссылки? Представьте, что в приложении десяток форм. В каждую форму передается ссылка на главную форму, а также возможно, что передается ссылка на какую-то дополнительную форму. Если в дальнейшем надо будет изменить логику взаимодействия форм, то возникнут сложности с рефакторингом.
Поэтому надо стараться **уменьшать связанность кода**, и если есть возможность передать ссылку через Application.OpenForms, то лучше так и делать.

Comment: а как ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос почему поле Owner = null?

Comment: @Grundy _"а как ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос почему поле Owner = null?"_ -- лучше дать один из нескольких правильных ответов, чем отвечать на множество неправильных, многие из которых даже задавать не надо, потому что в Visual Studio есть F11.

Comment: @Grundy а почему вы свой вопрос не задали @Monk? и почему минус поставили, хотите сказать, что Application.OpenForms не работает?

Comment: Потому что ваш ответ **никак** не привязан к заданному вопросу - вы просто получаете **какую-то** форму, в то время как в ответе @Monk, вполне себе решение задачи из вопроса. простой пример: если в программе несколько форм, вы получаете первую, а надо получать ссылку на ту, из которой открывается форма

Comment: @Grundy _"получаете какую-то форму"_ -- вы о чем? откройте вторую форму и посмотрите на результат вызова Application.OpenForms.OfType<Main>().First(); вы получите совершенно определенную форму.

Comment: _вы получите совершенно определенную форму_ если у вас открыто две формы тип `Main` - какую из них вы тут получите?

Comment: @Grundy _"у вас открыто две формы тип Main - какую из них вы тут получите?"_ -- для чего вам две Main? :) но если семантику названий типов вы не используете, то у контролов/форм есть свойство .Name и .Tag, а вообще надо всеми силами снижать связанность кода. и учить этому новичков. а вы против этого? или вы еще сами не сталкивались с проблемами, которые возникают из-за связанности?

Comment: Вы ушли от ответа :-)

Comment: @Grundy _"Вы ушли от ответа"_ -- а что вам непонятно? в программе бывает одна главная форма. вы спрашиваете: а если их две? я вам ответил что это неправильно, но даже в такой ситуации формы можно отличить, например, по значению .Name, а еще посмотрите на Form.ActiveForm. так что правильных вариантов немного, а вы хотите обсуждать неправильные и чтобы я отвечал? :)

Comment: _вам ответил что это неправильно, но даже в такой ситуации формы можно отличить, например, по значению .Name,_ и как вы узнаете по _Name_ в какой из форм был открыт диалог?

Comment: _а вы хотите обсуждать неправильные и чтобы я отвечал?_ - вы ответили на какой-то свой вопрос, вот я и пытаюсь хоть как-то привязать его к тому что спросил автор, а вы только добавляете варианты ответов на **свой** вопрос :)

Comment: @Grundy _"как вы узнаете по Name в какой из форм был открыт диалог?"_ -- для чего это диалогу знать? диалог вообще не должен знать кто его открыл. для примера посмотрите на OpenFileDialog. _"вы ответили на какой-то свой вопрос,"_ -- есть вопрос связанности кода, и он касается многих. вас еще не коснулся? про связанность кода я добавил в свой ответ.

Comment: Потому что в данном случае он вызывает функцию из своего owner

Comment: @Grundy _"он вызывает функцию из своего owner"_ -- и тем самым нарушает один из основных принципов ООП. почитайте мой ответ.

Comment: обратите внимание, что в обработчике `btnConnect_Click` диалог не закрывается, таким образом, ваш вариант с проверкой результата работать не будет

Comment: @Grundy  _"в обработчике btnConnect_Click диалог не закрывается"_ -- очевидно, что само по себе ничего не происходит. надо добавить код. и если нажатие btnConnect по смыслу соответствует OK, то надо закрыть диалог со значением DialogResult.OK. а если юзер нажал Esc, то надо закрыть диалог с соответствующим значением DialogResult. посмотрите как это сделано например в OpenFileDialog.

Comment: @Grundy пример диалога в ответе [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480924/)

Comment: @Stack, дочернюю форму не закрываю сразу т.к. в ней происходит ожидание до подключения клиента к серверу. В момент ожидания можно прервать попытку подключения, закрыв форму (при этом будет выведен диалог о том, что попытка соединения будет прекращена и вариантами о дальнейшем ожидании и прекращения). Как только соединение с сервером было установлено, форма закрывается самостоятельно.