# Как создать диалог, который закрывается при нажатии Esc?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как создать форму/диалог в WinForms, который закрывается при нажатии `Esc`, независимо от того в каком из контролов находится фокус? И как вернуть данные из диалога?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34143/discussion-on-question-by-stack-------).

Answer (score 9):

В том редком случае, если на форме нет кнопок вообще - что, на мой взгляд, редкость для диалога, вам стоит воспользоваться решением из соседних ответов.

Если на форме есть как минимум одна кнопка, её закрывающая, то стоит использовать стандартный механизм, описанный ниже.

---

Гораздо более простой способ сделать кнопку, реагирующую на <kbd>Esc</kbd> - это задать свойство [`Form.CancelButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton(v=vs.110).aspx).

Достаточно лишь бросить кнопку с надписью "Отмена" на форму, открыть свойства формы, и выбрать кнопку в списке CancelButton:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого эта кнопка будет нажиматься по <kbd>Esc</kbd> вне зависимости от текущего активного контрола.

Это действие так же автоматически задаст DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel в свойствах кнопки, что вызовет закрытие формы по нажатию либо на <kbd>Esc</kbd>, либо напрямую на кнопку.

Подробно эта тема, как и связанные с ней, рассмотрена в [MSDN: Практическое руководство. Создание кнопки "Отмена" в Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229630(v=vs.110).aspx)

Соответствующее свойство для кнопки по умолчанию - `Form.AcceptButton` - задает точно такое же поведение для Enter. В отличие от CancelButton, задание AcceptButton в дизайнере не выставляет DialogResult у выбранной кнопки, так что при необходимости автоматического закрытия по Enter придется задать это свойство вручуню.

---

Что делать, если на диалоге нет кнопки Cancel? например, диалог вообще не подразумевает отмены действия.

Т.к. на диалоге (по крайней мере на диалоговых окнах WinForms, которые обсуждаются в этом вопросе) есть хотя бы одна кнопка, то ее и стоит выбрать и как AcceptButton, и как CancelButton, обеспечив ее срабатывание и по <kbd>Enter</kbd>, и по <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: _"сделать кнопку, реагирующую на Esc"_ -- в диалоге не всегда нужна специальная кнопка cancel, т.к. достаточно того, что есть **кнопка закрытия окна** диалога.

Comment: При наличии в диалоге соответствующих кнопок, это, безусловно лучший вариант.

Comment: @Stack если вы про крестик в верхнем правом углу - то это не замена полноценной кнопки. Кнопка отметы подразумевает именно **отмену** действия (DialogResult.Cancel). Если на диалоге есть только одна кнопка (например, OK) - то такой диалог должен возвращать DialogResult.OK даже по Esc (легко проверить на стандартном MessageBox.Show). Т.е. в таком случае стоит поставить на форму одну кнопку OK, выбрать и как AcceptButton, как CancelButton и вручную выставить ей DialogResult.OK. И все заработает без хитрых хаков в коде.

Comment: @rdorn в диалоге всегда должна быть хоть одна кнопка. если на диалоге ровно одна кнопка - то крестик на форме или нажатие Esc должны возвращать тот же DialogResult, что и эта кнопка.

Comment: @Stack стоит перенести в ответ, наверное

Comment: @PashaPash _"в диалоге всегда должна быть хоть одна кнопка"_ -- в Windows 10 нажмите Win+S -- в диалоге поиска **нет никаких кнопок**.

Comment: @Stack а это и не диалог. и тем не менее - в нем есть не то что кнопка - в нем есть целое меню слева.

Comment: @Stack и какое это отношение имеет в вашему вопросу и предложенному вами же решению?

Comment: @Stack конкретно насчет кортаны - A dialog box is a **secondary** window that prompts an exchange of information between the user and the program - [официальный гайдлайн](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742499(v=vs.85).aspx). Окно поиска кортаны - не secondary, это вообще основное окно для поискового приложения.

Comment: _"это и не диалог."_ -- почему не диалог? это окно, с полем ввода, в котором что-то можно выбрать и нажать enter. _"и какое это отношение имеет в вашему вопросу"_ -- как сделать диалог работающий как поиск в Windows 10, т.е. надо сделать окно в котором есть поле ввода и есть реакция на Esc и Enter.

Comment: _"по крайней мере на диалоговых окнах WinForms"_ -- точнее в программах под WinForms обычно делают диалоги определенного вида. но вообще окна в WinForms могут быть любыми. и в Windows 7 можно сделать глобальный хук и открывать окно (созданное в WinForms приложении) похожее на поиск Windows 10, с таким же поведением и видом.

Comment: @Stack я предложил вам более простое решение вашего же вопроса. **Стандартным, общепринятым методом**. Срабатывающим в 99% случаев (кроме тех, когда вы пытаетесь сделать окно поиска 10-ки на WinForms - я бы сказал что в этом случае вы просто неправильно выбрали технологию). А вы, вместо того чтобы просто признать что это решение проще и удобнее, чем написание хитрого велсипеда с обработкой, - меняете вопрос. Если бы я, как вы, пытался выгородить свой велосипед - я бы на такое ответил - "сделайте кнопку невидимой, всего делов!". но не буду. Просто потому, что не люблю кривые решения.

Comment: _"я предложил вам более простое решение"_ -- решение с невидимой кнопкой интересное, но мне проще переопределить один метод ProcessCmdKey.   _"Срабатывающим в 99%"_ -- да, KeyPreview срабатывает не всегда. я добавил пример в мой ответ. _"я бы сказал что в этом случае вы просто неправильно выбрали технологию"_ -- WinForms - это обертка над GDI, большинство приложений под Windows используют GDI. А WPF появился относительно недавно и не подходит для многих проектов, которые написаны под WinForms.

Comment: @PashaPash "в диалоге всегда должна быть хоть одна кнопка", согласен, особенно если разговор про WinForms, но иногда, эксперимента ради или по требованию заказчика, может хотеться странного.

Answer (score 7):

Например, надо создать диалог, который возвращает

- `DialogResult.Cancel`, если нажали <kbd>Esc</kbd> или кнопку закрытия окна;
- `DialogResult.OK` и значение ключа, если нажали <kbd>Enter</kbd> в поле ввода.

Для перехвата нажатий можно использовать KeyPreview, но он работает не всегда. Пример в конце ответа.
Поэтому лучше переопределить метод ProcessCmdKey.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Dialog : Form {

    public int Key { get; private set; }

    public Dialog() {
        var tb = new TextBox() { Parent = this };
        tb.KeyDown += (s, e) => {                
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && tb.Text.Contains("1")) {
                this.Key = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
        };
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        var ret = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
    }        
}
```

Использовать диалог можно так

```
var d = new Dialog();
if(d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
   Console.WriteLine(d.Key);   // вывести значение ключа
```

---

KeyPreview не всегда подходит. Например, после открытия формы первое нажатие `Key.Left` не перехватывается.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        var t = new TextBox() { Parent = this };
        var l = new Label() { Parent = this };
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        this.Shown += (s, e) => l.Focus();
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left) {
            ((Form1)sender).Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Дополнение 4:

Для того, чтобы получить информацию о Windows окнах (windows styles, class name, windows rect и т.д.), можно использовать **HWndSpy** - исходный код [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836).

У всплывающих окон, диалогов, контекстных меню и т.д., в значении Windows Styles указывается WS_POPUP.

---

Дополнение 3:

Диалоговое окно или диалог - это окно для вывода информации и (или) получения ответа от пользователя.

Меню или контекстное меню - это окно, которое не содержит кнопки OK и/или Cancel и закрывается при нажатии Esc.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Пример меню]

---

Дополнение 2:

Форма/диалог/всплывающее окно, далее диалог - это окно с определенным поведением.

---

Дополнение 1:

Не во всех диалогах есть кнопки. Например, если нажать <kbd>Win+S</kbd> в  Windows 10, то откроется диалог, в котором нет кнопок OK и Cancel.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы привязали обработку клавиши к контролу, это может не сработать если контролов больше одного и нужный не в фокусе. Проще научить форму реагировать на клавиши не зависимо от наличия на ней контролов и текущего фокуса. За это отвечает  свойство KeyPreview. Я сам в свое время споткнулся об это когда писал простенькую игрушку, но уже, к сожалению, не помню, где откопал простое решение из моего ответа.

Comment: @rdorn _"Вы привязали обработку клавиши к контролу"_ -- как перехватить любое нажатие показано в методе ProcessCmdKey. но диалоги бывают разные. с большим количеством полей. и соверншенно не надо обработку всех нажатий выполнять в ProcessCmdKey. проще перехватить нажатие в обработчике определенного контрола. про это я и сказал в самом начале см. "если нажали Enter в поле ввода."

Comment: Минус за непонимание того, что в 90% случаев это решение является костылём. [Подробнее](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2286/178988).

Comment: @Qwertiy _"Минус за непонимание того, что в 90% случаев это решение является костылём."_ -- каких 90%. вы вообще хоть одно WinForms приложение написали? покажите мне код где вы создадите диалоговое меню без этого решения? :)

Comment: Понятия "диалоговое меню" не существует. Для стандартного меню есть готовый контрол. Календарик - уже интереснее. Но ничто из этого не принято называть диалогами. Это чистая подгонка вопроса под "я знаю только такое решение, ничего другого признавать не желаю, а мой ответ должен быть верным". Я написал на мете, как имело смысл поступить, и всем было бы хорошо. Всего лишь написать дополнения не в вопрос, а в ответ - и всем было бы хорошо. Но ты решил по-другому.

Comment: @Qwertiy _"Для стандартного меню есть готовый контрол."_ -- :) очевидно вы тоже не знаете, что в Windows есть только окна. и контролы - это обертки для окон. посмотрите ответ [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481593/196972)

Comment: `Managed Debugging Assistant 'RaceOnRCWCleanup' has detected a problem in '...\bin\Release\Code Validator.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use.  The RCW is in use on the active thread or another thread.  Attempting to free an in-use RCW can cause corruption or data loss.` - почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy _"Managed Debugging Assistant 'RaceOnRCWCleanup' has detected a problem"_ -- после чего это происходит? и как это относится к override ProcessCmdKey?

Comment: После того, как я такой код добавил к форме, содержащей WebBrowser. Форма закрывается, после чего всё рушится с исключением. Ладно, я потом потыкаю, может отдельным вопросом задам. Сейчас некогда разбираться.

Comment: @Qwertiy _"такой код добавил к форме, содержащей WebBrowser. Форма закрывается..."_ -- лучше как отдельный вопрос задать, а тут оставить ссылку.

Comment: [Проблема при наличии WebBrowser'а](/q/483157/178988)

Answer (score 7):

По умолчанию, форма, если содержит хотя бы один дочерний контрол, игнорирует обработку клавиш, даже если вы подписались на соответствующие события. Это поведение можно поменять изменив свойство формы KeyPreview = true (по умолчанию false). После этого события формы будут срабатывать на нажатия клавиш и вызывать соответствующие обработчики.

Рабочий пример. В конструкторе для проверки можно накидать на форму произвольных контролов и поиграть со значением указанного свойства. Для вызова в режиме диалога все тоже самое, но добавить присваивание значения свойству DialogResult.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            ((Form1)sender).Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _KeyPreview и Form1_KeyDown_ -- не всегда срабатывает. посмотрите пример в моем ответе.

Comment: Есть такое, когда нужна обработка клавиши, для которой уже задана стандартная реакция контролов. В таком случае да, либо переопределять унаследованные обработчики, либо прекращать извращаться и использовать общепринятые для WinForms способы, вроде AcceptButton и CancelButton как предлагает @PashaPash

Comment: _"Есть такое,"_ -- а для чего такое, если оно не работает в 100% случаев? :) _"переопределять унаследованные обработчики, либо прекращать извращаться"_ -- посмотрите мой ответ `override ProcessCmdKey` -- это как-раз и называется "переопределять". а прекращать извращаться - это вы о чем?

Comment: Диалоговые окна все таки подразумевают наличие хотя бы одной кнопки. Если вас смущает слово "извращаться", я не имел ввиду ни чего дурного, просто привычка называть так нестандартные решения, например диалоги без кнопок. В большинстве случаев такой диалог поставит пользователя в "тупик", хотя в отдельных случаях может оказаться и полезен.

Comment: _"Если вас смущает слово "извращаться", я не имел ввиду ни чего дурного, просто привычка называть так нестандартные решения, например диалоги без кнопок.."_ -- почему мой ответ без кнопок - это извращаться, а ваш ответ без кнопок (и не всегда работающий) - это хорошо? :)

Comment: я не говорил что это хорошо, это такое же извращение на случай странных желаний =)

Comment: А по поводу непосредственно вопроса, то с учетом последних изменений вопроса, для такого функционала диалог плохо подходит.

Comment: _"с учетом последних изменений вопроса, для такого функционала диалог плохо подходит."_ -- каких изменений? :) вопрос не менялся. обратите внимание на первое предложение: "Как создать **форму/диалог** в WinForms" -- форма - это и есть окно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34102/discussion-between-rdorn-and-stack).

Comment: _"Диалоговые окна все таки подразумевают наличие хотя бы одной кнопки."_ -- контекстные меню, просто меню - это диалоговые окна. но в Windows - это все просто окна. можете сами проверить. код на C# в ответе - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481586)