# Как получить список окон Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Приложение WinForms отображается в Windows как окно. Чтобы проверить, являются ли  контролы также окнами Windows, надо каким-то образом получить информацию об окне приложения и обо всех дочерних окнах.
Как это можно сделать на C#?
Т.е. нужен метод на C#, который на основе имени окна или номера процесса окна вернет информацию об окне и вложенных окнах. 
Этот метод поможет дать точный ответ на вопрос возникший [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480924): форма/диалог/меню/всплывающее окно/поиск кортаны (Win+S) - это окно или нет?

Answer (score 7):

Для получения списка окон вам придется прибегнуть к `WinApi` функции `EnumWindows`. Описание к этой функции вы можете найти [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx).

Полагаю вы хотите найти конкретное окошко, по этому прилагаю пример:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

// Delegate to filter which windows to include 
public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

/// <summary> Get the text for the window pointed to by hWnd </summary>
public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    if (size > 0)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(size + 1);
        GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, builder.Capacity);
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    return String.Empty;
}

/// <summary> Find all windows that match the given filter </summary>
/// <param name="filter"> A delegate that returns true for windows
///    that should be returned and false for windows that should
///    not be returned </param>
public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> FindWindows(EnumWindowsProc filter)
{
  IntPtr found = IntPtr.Zero;
  List<IntPtr> windows = new List<IntPtr>();

  EnumWindows(delegate(IntPtr wnd, IntPtr param)
  {
      if (filter(wnd, param))
      {
          // only add the windows that pass the filter
          windows.Add(wnd);
      }

      // but return true here so that we iterate all windows
      return true;
  }, IntPtr.Zero);

  return windows;
}

/// <summary> Find all windows that contain the given title text </summary>
/// <param name="titleText"> The text that the window title must contain. </param>
public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> FindWindowsWithText(string titleText)
{
    return FindWindows((wnd, param) => GetWindowText(wnd).Contains(titleText));
}
```

Применение:

```
var windows = FindWindowsWithText("Notepad");
```

Для получения позиции курсора можно использовать WinAPI функцию `GetCursorPos`

Использование:

```
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
    //позиция курсора: p.x  p.y
}
```

Что бы определить позицию курсора внутри окна можно воспользоваться этой функцией:

```
if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
{
    //p.x и p.y относительны вашего окна
}
```

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: а как получить окно под мышью? т.е. я запускаю программу, она topmost, небольшого размера, в ней textbox. мышь может находиться над любым другим окном, а в textbox выводится hwnd под мышью.

Comment: @Stack обновил ответ. По идее с помощью этого набора функций должно хватит для решения вашей задачи, но на практике не решал такую задачу.

Comment: hwnd под мышью можно получить вызвав функцию WindowFromPoint. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно для вас подойдёт что-то вроде:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process[] ProcessesList = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Это список всех процессов.
Теперь можно сделать так, чтобы получить заголовок окна:

```
ProcessesList[i].MainWindowTitle;
```

если что-то другое, то вы наверняка найдёте нужный метод на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно ли делать это на C#? Есть же такая программа, как Spy++:

[image: Сервис - Spy++]

Comment: Вы не поверите, я предложил то же самое - и получил возмущение от топиастера - мол, я забалтываю вопрос, и ответ мой ответом не является. пришлось удалить :)

Comment: spyxx.exe есть не у всех. и как с ее помощью получить hwnd для окна поиска Win+S? или любого другого диалога или меню?

Comment: @PashaPash _"я предложил то же самое - и получил возмущение от топиастера - мол, я забалтываю вопрос, и ответ мой ответом не является. пришлось удалить :)"_ -- но вы же тратили время. и выбросили ответ в урну. теперь вы опять начнете требовать у меня  переделать свой вопрос? :)

Comment: @Stack нет, но я считаю что этот вопрос создан с целью показать всем что я (якобы!) не знал что диалоги - это окна (я ведь утверждал что не все окна - диалоги, а это ведь одно и то же!). и да, ваш комментарий выше - о чем он? какое отношение он имеет к ответу?

Comment: если надо получить инфу по контекстному меню, то в spyxx.exe это невозможно. т.к. если в нем вызвать Find, то контекстное меню закроется. такой проблемы нет в HWndSpy - исходник [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836)