# Как при нажатии кнопки Ок закрыть 2 форму?

Tags: c#

Есть 2 формы.

На 1 форме список данных и парочка кнопок, если нажимаю кнопку редактировать то выходит 2 форма, где я вводу какие то данные и после нажимаю ОК.

Вопрос как при нажатии кнопки Ок закрыть 2 форму?

Comment: WinForm или WPF?

Answer (score 3):

Открываете через диалог

```
using (MyForm fMyForm = new MyForm())
{
    if (fMyForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

а во второй форме при нажатии на кнопку вызываете

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; 
this.Close();
```

Comment: А зачем именно `dr.ToString() == "OK"`? Почему не `dr == DialogResult.OK`? или вообще `fMyForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK`?

Comment: @kodv, согласен, просто, в качестве одного из вариантов, можно было и через `switch`

Comment: Кстати, DialogResult можно задать прямо в свойствах кнопки и вообще не писать код обработки нажатия на нее - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481380/177221

Answer (score 1):

**Решение для WPF** 
Вызываем вторую форму

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();
if (form.DialogResult == true)
{
...
}
```

В вызванной форме при  нажатии кнопки "ОК"

```
this.DialogResult = true;
Close();
```

Для кнопки "Отмена"

```
Close();
```